# Как переходить на другой viewcontroller по условию?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Я хотел бы переходить с одного контроллера на другой, если в Userdefault с ключом имеет какие то значения
Пишу так

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lang") == nil{
        chooseElement()
        //change view backgroundimage part 2
        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: self.myview.bounds)
        backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "Background_1")
        backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        backgroundImage.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth] // In
        self.myview.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)

    }
    else{
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

На другой контроллер он не переходит
Однако если я вставлю этот код в кнопку и нажму ее, то переход происходит
Как сделать его автоматическим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в методе `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`, `view` вашего контроллера еще не добавленно в иерархию window.

Как решение можно делать этот переход в методе `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` Но тогда вы можете увидеть на долю секунды ваш `mainViewController`.

Также решением может быть добавление `UINavigationController` и определение `rootViewController` вашего `mainViewController`. 
Тогда решением может быть переход

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

Этот метод можно вызвать и во `viewDidLoad()` а также во `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`